# Reading a file into variable without newlines

Tags: bash

I am not expert with bash but I would imagine this would be a simple script. I am trying to read a file with a few lines into a single bash variable **without** the new lines.

My current script reads them in but keeps the presence of newlines

```
options=$(<vm.options)
echo "$options"
```

The file looks something like this:

```
-Random 1
-Letters2
-Occur 3
-In
-Passwords9
```

The script would read this into a variable where its output would look like:

```
-Random 1 -Letters2 -Occur 3 -In -Passwords9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply replace the new line with `tr` :

```
options=$(cat lf | tr -s '\n' ' ')
```

Comment: Close but doesn't separate each line with a space for the desired output.

Comment: Missed the space requirement. Answer updated to handle this

Answer (score 2):

You can do search/replace in bash after reading file content:

```
options=$(<vm.options)
# replace \n with space
options="${options//$'\n'/ }"
```

Now examine `options` variable:

```
declare -p options
```

```
declare -- options="-Random 1 -Letters2 -Occur 3 -In -Passwords9"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the only solution that takes care of new lines and creates a space between each line.

Comment: Did this solution not work for some case for you?

Answer (score 2):

This also produces the desired output:

```
echo "\
-Random 1
-Letters2
-Occur 3
-In
-Passwords9" > tmp

var=$(cat tmp | tr -s '\n' ' ')

echo $var
```

resulting in:

```
-Random 1 -Letters2 -Occur 3 -In -Passwords9
```

the part with `cat` is not pretty (and may break in specific instances) but it works for this case.

Comment: This doesn't take in account `\n`, so everything remains on a newline with `cat`.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid search and replace and line endings issues:

```
options=$(echo $(cat vm.options))
```

To prove you got the newlines removed:

```
echo "$options"
```

and see just one line.

Comment: `echo` appends a newline. Your proof would need to look like this: `echo -n "$options"`

Comment: Indeed, echo adds a newline, so the proof should not show an **extra** newline before the next shell prompt. You do want the newline before the next shell prompt for readability.